# HTML 5 , CSS3 support PHP IDE?

Tags: ide, html, css

Is it available for HTML5 and CSS3 support PHP IDE ? In this days, I'm using espresso in Mac. But espresso is lacking dictionaries for HTML5. So, I want to know , What IDE support HTML5 and CSS3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I would definitely recommend checking out a JetBrains product.  They've got some new IDEs for [Python](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html) and [PHP](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/index.html).  I've been using PyCharm for quite a while now and its been excellent.  It looks like [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/index.html) does support HTML5 - so I assume the Python and PHP equivalents do as well.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess a good one would be [aptana studio](http://aptana.com/).

It is very popular and has a lot of features that support html5 and css3, also a lot of library support such as jquery.

If you think it is too heavy, like me, you can also use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with [pdt](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt), it has decent support for html5 and css3.

Answer (score 0):

The newest Version of Adobe Dreamweaver also is a charm, if you are willing to pay for and don't rely on freeware

Comment: True, it works great, I use it a lot too. Pretty expensive tho.